# How can I create a filter to filer 2 tables with no connection

Tags: powerbi

In my PowerBI model, I have 2 tables,

Table1

| category1LevelCount | category2LevelCount | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 7 | Sept |
| 8 | 9 | Oct |
| 13 | 11 | Nov |

Table 2

| category1Min | category2Min | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1023 | Sept |
| 1003 | 1110 | Oct |
| 1034 | 11231 | Nov |

In my Power BI, I have 2 clustered column chart2, 1 for each table and the x-axis is `month` and y is the values (e.g. category1LevelCount , category2LevelCount  in 1 chart,
whereas category1Min, category2Min).

My question is these 2 tables has no relationship, but I want to create a filter so that when I set the filter to 'category1',

- chart 1 will show only category1LevelCount
- chat 2 will show only category1Min

(i.e. only show y-axis with 'category1' in all charts)

Can you please tell me if that is possible?

Comment: did you check [DAX Function (Relationships management)](https://dax.guide/userelationship/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this use-case you need to unpivot your data, since your tables do not have the category designation as rows in a column. Your `Table 1` must look like this:

| month | Attribute | Value | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sept | category1LevelCount | 3 | Category 1 |
| Sept | category2LevelCount | 7 | Category 2 |
| Oct | category1LevelCount | 8 | Category 1 |
| Oct | category2LevelCount | 9 | Category 2 |
| Nov | category1LevelCount | 13 | Category 1 |
| Nov | category2LevelCount | 11 | Category 2 |

And your `Table 2` must look like this:

| month | Attribute | Value | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sept | category1Min | 1000 | Category 1 |
| Sept | category2Min | 1023 | Category 2 |
| Oct | category1Min | 1003 | Category 1 |
| Oct | category2Min | 1110 | Category 2 |
| Nov | category1Min | 1034 | Category 1 |
| Nov | category2Min | 11231 | Category 2 |

You can paste this code into a blank query to see how to do this simple transformation on your minimal data:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlbSUTIH4uDUghKlWJ1oJQsgxxKI/ZMhfEOQCkNDIOGXX6YUGwsA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [category1LevelCount = _t, category2LevelCount = _t, month = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"category1LevelCount", Int64.Type}, {"category2LevelCount", Int64.Type}, {"month", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"month"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Category", each if Text.StartsWith([Attribute], "category1") then "Category 1" else "Category 2")
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

After loading these tables, you need to create a simple table that contains the Category selection. You can do this in many ways, but the simplest is probably to click "Enter data" in the Home -> Data tab, and create a 1-column table like this:

[image]

We will use this small table to push the Category filter to your two fact tables. When the tables are in the data model, connect them using relationships. In the Model view, it should look like this:

[image]

The additional small table will act as a filter on both `Table 1` and `Table 2` simultaneously, achieving the effect you asked for.

When you get to this point, you can create charts based on the `month`, `Attribute` and `Value` columns from `Table 1` to create your first chart. The settings for a clustered bar chart are shown below, this will create one bar per month, with height according to the value column, and colors/attribute in legend according to the Attribute column:

[image]

From `Table 2` to create your second chart. Use your `Categories[Category]` column as a slicer, and set the slicer to single-select if you want to force a single-category selection:

[image]